# @CreationTimestamp doesn't work with H2 and Oracle10gDialect

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a class Request:

```
@Entity
public class Request {
  @CreationTimestamp
  private Date createdDate;
}
```

And when I'm testing it using:

```
Request request = requestRepository.save(new Request());
request.getCreatedDate();
```

for some reason getCreatedDate is still null.

I'm using H2 with Oracle10gDialect for tests (it was working when I was using a default dialect for H2).

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you defined Request class as an entity in config file?

Comment: Try adding @Entity for Request class.

Comment: It is defined as an entity - I've updated the description.

Comment: In my case it was a silly `@Column(insertable = false)`, instead of `@Column(updatable = false)`. This has nothing to do with H2 of course, but maybe it will help someone out!